# How to open Intent Chooser for browsing Sdcard folder and it's contents in android

Tags: java, android, attachment, sd-card, doc

I am trying to to attach files which places on some folder in Sdcard. I am able to fetch files from gallery and other media type but no luck so far to browse sdcard so i could choose text files (Doc, docx, pdf etc). The requirement is very close to Email-attach menu option in Email-Application of Android device which allows user view Sdcard folders by Intent.

If anybody have such an experience to browse Sdcard and its Contents please share code or guide me. many Thanks in advance.

Recently i am using following code to open But it is not showing Sdcard option`:-

```
Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath()));
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setData(startDir);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: might help you
https://github.com/KamleshArya/Android-Demo-Project/blob/master/src/com/kamlesh/androidminiproject/FileOperationsWrite.java

Comment: I am sorry to say but i don't have any specific file from Sdcard but i want to choose any of file once Sdcard is viewable. See attach file option at Email Application for best understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this ...

```
          public OnClickListener buttonOnClickBrowse = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
                loadFileList();

               showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);

        }
};
```

// *******************************************************************

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

// Check if the first level of the directory structure is the one showing
private Boolean firstLvl = true;

private Item [] fileList;
private File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");
private String chosenFile;
private static final int DIALOG_LOAD_FILE = 1000;

ArrayAdapter adapter1;

private void loadFileList()
    {
        try
            {
                path.mkdirs();
            } catch (SecurityException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG , "unable to write on the sd card ");
            }

        // Checks whether path exists
        if (path.exists())
            {
                FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File dir , String filename)
                        {
                            File sel = new File(dir , filename);
                            // Filters based on whether the file is hidden
                            // or not
                            return (sel.isFile() || sel.isDirectory()) && !sel.isHidden();

                        }
                };

                String [] fList = path.list(filter);
                fileList = new Item[fList.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++)
                    {
                        fileList [i] = new Item(fList [i] , R.drawable.file_icon);

                        // Convert into file path
                        File sel = new File(path , fList [i]);

                        // Set drawables
                        if (sel.isDirectory())
                            {
                                fileList [i].icon = R.drawable.directory_icon;
                                Log.d("DIRECTORY" , fileList [i].file);
                            } else
                            {
                                Log.d("FILE" , fileList [i].file);
                            }
                    }

                if (!firstLvl)
                    {
                        Item temp[] = new Item[fileList.length + 1];
                        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
                            {
                                temp [i + 1] = fileList [i];
                            }
                        temp [0] = new Item("Up" , R.drawable.directory_up);
                        fileList = temp;
                    }
            } else
            {
                Log.e(TAG , "path does not exist");
            }

        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(ImageReader.this , android.R.layout.select_dialog_item , android.R.id.text1 , fileList) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent)
                {

                    View view = super.getView(position , convertView , parent);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                    // put the image on the text view
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(fileList [position].icon , 0 , 0 , 0);

                    // add margin between image and text (support various
                    // screen
                    // densities)
                    int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                    return view;

                }
        };

    }

private class Item {
    public String file;
    public int icon;

    public Item(String file , Integer icon) {
        this.file = file;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
        {
            return file;
        }
}

File setetedFileName;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);

        if (fileList == null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG , "No files loaded");
                dialog = builder.create();
                return dialog;
            }

        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_LOAD_FILE:
                builder.setTitle("choose ur file");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter1 , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog , int which)
                        {
                            chosenFile = fileList [which].file;
                            File sel = new File(path + "/" + chosenFile);
                            setetedFileName = sel;
                            if (sel.isDirectory())
                                {
                                    firstLvl = false;

                                    // Adds chosen directory to list
                                    str.add(chosenFile);
                                    fileList = null;
                                    path = new File(sel + "");

                                    loadFileList();

                                    removeDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                                    showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                                    Log.d(TAG , path.getAbsolutePath());

                                }

                            // Checks if 'up' was clicked
                            else if (chosenFile.equalsIgnoreCase("up") && !sel.exists())
                                {

                                    // present directory removed from list
                                    String s = str.remove(str.size() - 1);

                                    // path modified to exclude present
                                    // directory
                                    path = new File(path.toString().substring(0 , path.toString().lastIndexOf(s)));
                                    fileList = null;

                                    // if there are no more directories in
                                    // the list, then
                                    // its the first level
                                    if (str.isEmpty())
                                        {
                                            firstLvl = true;
                                        }
                                    loadFileList();

                                    removeDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                                    showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                                    Log.d(TAG , path.getAbsolutePath());

                                }
                            // File picked
                            else
                                {
                                    // Perform action with file picked

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "" + setetedFileName.getAbsolutePath() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                }

                        }
                });
                break;
        }
        dialog = builder.show();
        return dialog;
    }

         // *******************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is that, pragmatically show required files and folders in your app and let user select the files to be attached.

As far as showing particular folder through intent is concerned, seems there is no built in app to do that.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896386/showing-user-a-particular-folder-in-sd-card-and-allow-to-select-file) link.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can see this feature in Attach Option in Email-Application of Android Device.